# Git Tf installation on Mac Osx 10.8

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, git, git-tf

I have tried to integrate Git Tf with Xcode 4.5.1 and Mac OSx 10.8. I have followed the steps which are written at : " http://www.hhogdev.com/Blog/2013/January/ios-git-tfs-integration-step-by-step.aspx " . But at 5. step terminal has given error  " 'tf' is not a git command." Then I have looked at the html files that are given with the git-tf installation folder. It has written that it is for MacOsX version 10.5 to 10.6. 
  Is it possible to use git tf with Mac OsX 10.8? If yes, is there any good tutorial about how to integrate git-tf with Mac osx 10.8? 
  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have written the correct path into $PATH in step 2.4. It  can't find your git-tf. That's why you get the "tf is not git command"

Answer (score 2):

I made the mistake of setting my PATH in .bash_profile to:
`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/git-tf`
following the instructions here https://gittf.codeplex.com/wikipage?referringTitle=Documentation. 
When the archive utility extracts the files it places them in a folder named `git-tf-x.x.x.xxxxxx`. Because I extracted into a directory named `git-tf/` I adjusted my PATH variable in .bash_profile to
`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/git-tf/git-tf-x.x.x.xxxxxx`
and the command was found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out already but I had the same problem. I eventually figured it out by moving my git-tf install to my /Users/{useraccount} directory as per the instructions example. I originally installed my git-tf to my /Users/{useraccount}/Desktop directory and thats what gave me the error. I'm on OSX 10.8 so it definitely works. If you haven't figured it out let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the java? 
Did you add the environment variable to your bash?
Here's the link for step by step in GIT TF installation: http://mariabrinas.com/?p=232